# Storm: How do I get the transfer latency between bolts?

Tags: azure, apache-storm, metrics, azure-hdinsight

Note: I'm using an Azure HDInsight Storm Linux Cluster .

There is a Storm UI that gives fairly good metrics but it doesn't give the latency between bolts. So I put in some logging statements at the beginning and end of each bolt. This way I can calculate the time between bolts. Unfortunately this value comes back negative some times... :/ but that should be impossible. I'm using four worker processes (JVMs) so I'm assuming when a message goes from one JVM to another their system clock's aren't in sync.

Could anyone answer either of these questions:

```
1) How to reliably get the transfer latency between bolts. 
2) How to sync the system clock between worker processes.
```

Comment: y u no accept or response to any answer of your questions? show the people trying to help you some gratitude or if you still have any questions ask 'em on the post. If users answere your question they deserve feedback/their reputations

Answer (score 2):

Very hard -- if you want to do it very reliable, you would need to use `System.nanoTime()` -- this does not access the system clock and **cannot** be synchronized over machines -- thus, it only works of both workers run on the same physical machine.

For multi-machine measurements, you can use NTP to sync the system clocks. But this will be less accurate.